# Parameter plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am trying to produce a plot using `ggplot2` on the UNvotes data. I am trying to parameterize the plot in Rmarkdown but getting the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `perc_yes`. x non-numeric argument to binary operator i Input `perc_yes` is `sum(vote == "yes")/n`. i The error occurred in group 1: yr = 1991.
```

Code:

```
single_country %>% 
  inner_join(un_roll_calls %>% select(rcid, date), by = "rcid") %>%
  mutate(yr = year(date)) %>%
  group_by(yr) %>%
  summarize(perc_yes = sum(vote == "yes") / n) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = yr, y = perc_yes)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() + 
  labs(title = plot_title)
```

Not sure if it is lacking some recoding issues or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line before `ggplot`

```
summarise(perc_yes = sum(vote == "yes") / n) %>%
```

with this line:

```
summarise(n = n(), perc_yes = sum(vote == "yes") / n) %>%
```

Actually you are missing `n = n()`

[image]